# Visual Studio SSRS project file error: The project requires users input. Reload the project for more information

Tags: visual-studio, reporting-services

I have a Visual Studio solution with about 30 SSRS Projects.  Most of the project files load just fine (e.g. "Sales.rptproj").  However, one of the project files have errors ("Subscription Reports.rptproj").  The XML Code is included below; and it looks fine to me.  Anyone know why this one project won't load?  My VS versions are listed below.

Project tree error message:

> The project requires users input.  Reload the project for more
>   information.

When I right click and reload the Visual Studio error message is:

> There is an error in XML document (2,2).

**Visual Studio Versions**

```
+--------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------+
| Microsoft                                              | Microsoft Visual Studio                                |
|   Visual Studio Community 2015                         |   Community 2015                                       |
|     Version 14.0.25431.01 Update 3                     |     Version 14.0.25431.01 Update 3                     |
|     Microsoft .NET Framework                           |     Microsoft .NET Framework                           |
|     Version 4.8.03752                                  |     Version 4.8.03752                                  |
|                                                        |                                                        |
|     Installed Version: Community                       |     Installed Version: Community                       |
|                                                        |                                                        |
+--------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------+
| SQL Server Data Tools                                  | SQL Server Data Tools   14.0.61712.050                 |
|   14.0.61709.290                                       |     Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools                    |
|     Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools                    |     * Version 17.3                                     |
|      * Version 17.30                                   |                                                        |
|                                                        |                                                        |
+--------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------+
| SQL Server Reporting Services                          | SQL Server Reporting                                   |
|   14.0.1012.227                                        |   Services   14.0.1016.232                             |
|     Microsoft SQL Server Reporting Services Designers  |     Microsoft SQL Server Reporting Services Designers  |
|     Version 14.0.1012.227                              |     Version 14.0.1016.232                              |
|                                                        |                                                        |
+--------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------+
```

**Visual Studio error**

[image]

**["Subscription Reports.rptproj"] - problems**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="14.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'Debug' ">
    <FullPath>Debug</FullPath>
    <Platform>Win32</Platform>
    <OutputPath>bin\Debug</OutputPath>
    <ErrorLevel>2</ErrorLevel>
    <OverwriteDatasets>False</OverwriteDatasets>
    <OverwriteDataSources>False</OverwriteDataSources>
    <TargetServerVersion>SSRS2016</TargetServerVersion>
    <TargetReportFolder>/Subscription Reports</TargetReportFolder>
    <TargetDatasetFolder>/Testing Folder</TargetDatasetFolder>
    <TargetDatasourceFolder>/Data Sources/01-DEV</TargetDatasourceFolder>
    <TargetReportPartFolder>Report Parts</TargetReportPartFolder>
    <TargetServerURL>http://gcod049/ReportServer</TargetServerURL>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'DebugLocal' ">
    <FullPath>DebugLocal</FullPath>
    <Platform>Win32</Platform>
    <OutputPath>bin\DebugLocal</OutputPath>
    <ErrorLevel>2</ErrorLevel>
    <OverwriteDatasets>False</OverwriteDatasets>
    <OverwriteDataSources>False</OverwriteDataSources>
    <TargetServerVersion>SSRS2016</TargetServerVersion>
    <TargetReportFolder>Subscription Reports</TargetReportFolder>
    <TargetDatasetFolder>Datasets</TargetDatasetFolder>
    <TargetDatasourceFolder>Data Sources</TargetDatasourceFolder>
    <TargetReportPartFolder>Report Parts</TargetReportPartFolder>
    <TargetServerURL>http://localhost/reportserver</TargetServerURL>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'Release' ">
    <FullPath>Release</FullPath>
    <Platform>Win32</Platform>
    <OutputPath>bin\Release</OutputPath>
    <ErrorLevel>2</ErrorLevel>
    <OverwriteDatasets>False</OverwriteDatasets>
    <OverwriteDataSources>False</OverwriteDataSources>
    <TargetServerVersion>SSRS2016</TargetServerVersion>
    <TargetReportFolder>Subscription Reports</TargetReportFolder>
    <TargetDatasetFolder>Datasets</TargetDatasetFolder>
    <TargetDatasourceFolder>Data Sources</TargetDatasourceFolder>
    <TargetReportPartFolder>Report Parts</TargetReportPartFolder>
    <TargetServerURL>http://localhost/reportserver</TargetServerURL>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <State>$base64$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</State>
    <DataSources>@(DataSource)</DataSources>
    <DataSets>@(DataSet)</DataSets>
    <Reports>@(Report)</Reports>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <DataSource Include="Gmenu.rds" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Report Include="Feed Ingredient Weekly Price Avg.rdl" />
    <Report Include="GCM JBHT Truck Fuel Use Report.rdl" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\Reporting Services\Microsoft.ReportingServices.MSBuilder.targets" />
</Project>
```

**["Sales.rptproj"] - working fine**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="14.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'Debug' ">
    <FullPath>Debug</FullPath>
    <Platform>Win32</Platform>
    <OutputPath>bin\Debug</OutputPath>
    <ErrorLevel>2</ErrorLevel>
    <OverwriteDatasets>False</OverwriteDatasets>
    <OverwriteDataSources>False</OverwriteDataSources>
    <TargetServerVersion>SSRS2016</TargetServerVersion>
    <TargetReportFolder>/Sales</TargetReportFolder>
    <TargetDatasetFolder>Datasets</TargetDatasetFolder>
    <TargetDatasourceFolder>/Data Sources/03-PROD</TargetDatasourceFolder>
    <TargetReportPartFolder>Report Parts</TargetReportPartFolder>
    <TargetServerURL>http://gcod049/ReportServer</TargetServerURL>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'DebugLocal' ">
    <FullPath>DebugLocal</FullPath>
    <Platform>Win32</Platform>
    <OutputPath>bin\DebugLocal</OutputPath>
    <ErrorLevel>2</ErrorLevel>
    <OverwriteDatasets>False</OverwriteDatasets>
    <OverwriteDataSources>False</OverwriteDataSources>
    <TargetServerVersion>SSRS2016</TargetServerVersion>
    <TargetReportFolder>Sales</TargetReportFolder>
    <TargetDatasetFolder>Datasets</TargetDatasetFolder>
    <TargetDatasourceFolder>Data Sources</TargetDatasourceFolder>
    <TargetReportPartFolder>Report Parts</TargetReportPartFolder>
    <TargetServerURL>http://localhost/reportserver</TargetServerURL>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'Release' ">
    <FullPath>Release</FullPath>
    <Platform>Win32</Platform>
    <OutputPath>bin\Release</OutputPath>
    <ErrorLevel>2</ErrorLevel>
    <OverwriteDatasets>False</OverwriteDatasets>
    <OverwriteDataSources>False</OverwriteDataSources>
    <TargetServerVersion>SSRS2016</TargetServerVersion>
    <TargetReportFolder>Sales</TargetReportFolder>
    <TargetDatasetFolder>Datasets</TargetDatasetFolder>
    <TargetDatasourceFolder>Data Sources</TargetDatasourceFolder>
    <TargetReportPartFolder>Report Parts</TargetReportPartFolder>
    <TargetServerURL>http://localhost/reportserver</TargetServerURL>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <State>$base64$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</State>
    <DataSources>@(DataSource)</DataSources>
    <DataSets>@(DataSet)</DataSets>
    <Reports>@(Report)</Reports>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <DataSet Include="listWarehouse.rsd" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <DataSource Include="AX2012R3.rds" />
    <DataSource Include="Gmenu.rds" />
    <DataSource Include="Jet Merged AX DW.rds" />
    <DataSource Include="ProductionPlanning.rds" />
    <DataSource Include="ReportServer.rds" />
    <DataSource Include="vpEDI_Data.rds" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Report Include="Customer Load Comparison.rdl" />
    <Report Include="Customers.rdl" />
    <Report Include="FPAToShipByWhse_subOrderDetails.rdl" />
    <Report Include="Frozen Product Available to Ship by Whse.rdl" />
    <Report Include="Invoice Paid By Date.rdl" />
    <Report Include="Market Pricing Report.rdl" />
    <Report Include="Nash ASN Report.rdl" />
    <Report Include="NotesSubReport.rdl" />
    <Report Include="Open Orders.rdl" />
    <Report Include="OpenOrdersHeaders.rdl" />
    <Report Include="Plant Daily Shortage Report.rdl" />
    <Report Include="TMS Rebate Activity_Vance 20171219.1100.rdl" />
    <Report Include="TMS Rebate Activity_Vance 20171220.1018.rdl" />
    <Report Include="USF ASN Report.rdl" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\Reporting Services\Microsoft.ReportingServices.MSBuilder.targets" />
</Project>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error was resolved by deleting the "rptproj.rsuser" File

1. Opening file explorer
2. Navigate to the project folder
3. delete the “rptproj.rsuser” file
4. Reload the project

For example:

[image]

Comment: What worked for me was removing `*.rptproj.user` file for 2017 VS